# Compare two generic ArrayList - java

Tags: java

I have two Classes "Haus" and "Wohnung" . I put them in a separate ArrayList.
Can i compare two different ArrayList which Object is cheaper for example: "Wohnung" price 20000 Dollar 
and "Haus" price 30000 Dollar?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wie viele Immobilien wollen Sie vergleichen?");
    ArrayList<Wohnung>WohnungListe = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Haus>HausListe = new ArrayList<>();

    int anzhl = sc.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    double x, y ;
    int zahl;
    while (i < anzhl) {
        System.out.println("Ist diese Wohnung was ? (1) wenn Wohnung (2) wenn Haus ");
        zahl = sc.nextInt();
        if(zahl ==1) {
            System.out.println("Welche W1 Kooridante ");
            x = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Welche W2 Kooridante ");
            y =sc.nextDouble();
            Wohnung w = new Wohnung(x,y);
            WohnungListe.add(w);
            i++;
        }
        if(zahl ==2) {
            System.out.println("Welche H1 Kooridante ");
            x = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Welche H2 Kooridante ");
            y =sc.nextDouble();
            Haus h = new Haus(x,y);
            HausListe.add(h);
            i++;
        }
    }   
    if(WohnungListe.equals(HausListe)) {
        System.out.println("Fan");
    }
        System.out.println("Wohnung "+WohnungListe.toString());
        System.out.println("Haus "+HausListe.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make them have a common superclass with the price in it. That way you could sort and compare them regardless of whether they're houses or flats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the equals method of both the objects. You can do it like this:

```
class A {
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // return whatever you want depending on what you want in order for that to be equal.
    }
}
```

In you're case, of course, that would be put in you're `Haus` and `Wohung` classes. For example, if you're comparing prices, you can do this:

```
class Haus {
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // I won't show how to safely down-cast.
        Wohung w = (Wohung) other;
        return w.price == price;
    }
}
```

And the same for the other class, except switch `Wohung` to `Haus`. The `ArrayList` will call the equals method, and it will be equal if you ovveride the `equals` method correctly.

But you can always just iterate through both lists if you don't want to ovveride the equals method.

```
                 // I'm going to assume they are of equal size.
for(int i = 0; i < WohungListe.size(); i ++) {
    if(! (/* Check if they are equal */) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java documentation says:

> "two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements
>   in the same order".

Thus, `WohnungListe.equals(HausListe)` will always be false.

If you want to compare WohnungListe and HausListe by some common field (e.g. price), iterate over both lists and compare each pair separately.

Comment: When i test this :   System.out.println(WohnungListe.equals(HausListe));
then it gives me true back .

Comment: Before calling equals(), make sure both of the lists are not empty.